# Applying functions designed to take base R model objects on Parsnip objects?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidymodels, r-parsnip

Most package authors design functions to take in the traditional R model objects like is there anyway to feed them a model object created by `parsnip` package and tidymodels?

an example:

```
model <- lm(mpg ~ am + cyl + wt + hp, data = mtcars)
car::avPlots(model, terms = . ~ am + cyl + wt + hp)
```

but if you create the model through tidymodels it won't work since the output object is different#fit_ex5_1 <-

```
model_pars <-
  linear_reg() %>% 
  set_engine("lm") %>% 
  fit(mpg ~ am + cyl + wt + hp, data = mtcar)

#this doesn't work:
car::avPlots(model_pars, terms = . ~ am + cyl + wt + hp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine there may be various methods depending on the type of model. In the case of `lm()` you can extract `parsnip_model$fit`, which is an object of class `lm`, like the output of `lm()`:

```r
parsnip_model <- linear_reg() |>
    fit(mpg ~ am + cyl + wt + hp, data = mtcars)

class(parsnip_model$fit) # lm

# Compare the models excl. [["call"]] which will be different
all.equal(
    parsnip_model$fit[names(parsnip_model$fit) != "call"],
    model[names(model) != "call"]
) # TRUE

car::avPlots(parsnip_model$fit) # this works
```

[image]

Note: I did not include the `terms` argument to the `car::avPlots()` call as the plot includes all the terms by default, but the code runs if you include them.

Answer (score 4):

There is a function, `extract_fit_engine()`, that will return the underlying model object if you have a parsnip model fit or a fitted workflow.

```r
library(tidymodels)

linear_reg() %>% 
  set_engine("lm") %>% 
  fit(mpg ~ am + cyl + wt + hp, data = mtcars) %>% 
  extract_fit_engine()
#> 
#> Call:
#> stats::lm(formula = mpg ~ am + cyl + wt + hp, data = data)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)           am          cyl           wt           hp  
#>    36.14654      1.47805     -0.74516     -2.60648     -0.02495
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I didn't know about this. Interestingly, if you look at the source with `getAnywhere(extract_fit_engine.model_fit)` you will see it just does the same thing as my answer: `if (any(names(x) == "fit")) {return(x$fit)}`, else `rlang::abort("Internal error: The model fit does not have an engine fit.")`. Still, nice that there is a helper function to do this, in case one day it changes.